# sql server - bulk insert error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using bulk insert and getting below error:

Note: The data in the load file is *not* beyong the configured column length

## Running Command:

bulk insert load_data      from 'C:\temp\dataload\load_file.txt'       with (firstrow = 1, fieldterminator = '0x09', rowterminator = '\n',MAXERRORS = 0, ERRORFILE = 'C:\temp\dataload\load_file')

## Contents of load file:

```
user_name   file_path   asset_owner   city      import_date    
admin       C:\         admin         toronto   04/12/2012
```

## Error:

Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 6 (validated).
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Can you provide load_data schema?

Comment: Is column 6 by chance the last field in the row? It sounds like the field or rowterminator may be incorrect. I've seen this in the past. Since it doesn't find the terminator, it thinks the field/row extends on to the next field or row. Just a guess.

Comment: You don't appear to have 6 columns...  Also, formatting is a little different than you might otherwise expect here on SO, so I tweaked your data so that it lines up... which unfortunately resulted in the delimiter tabs going missing (although personally I prefer non-whitespace characters for this anyways).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of columns was incorrect. I had recently changed the table schema but forgotten to do a refresh on the table.

Comment: same error for me in the same situation: 8 table columns but 7 fields in my CSV

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by changing the data type in the schema. I had date type changed to nvarchar... It worked